# Can you define a sensible probability measure on the set of countable transitive models of ZFC?

Tags: probability-theory, logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It is well known that the set of hereditarily countable sets  $H(\omega_1)$ —or, if you prefer, $H_{\omega_1}$— has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, and I understand that every countable transitive model (ctm) of ZFC lives in this set. So, if there were a way to give $H(\omega_1)$ a sensible structure (separable metric, for instance) one might try to calculate the probability that a ctm satisfy CH (to name just one example).

I imagine that this idea has been explored and rejected quickly, but I couldn't find anything related to it.

A prior requirement, as I mentioned, would be to have some “definable” topology in the descriptive-set-theoretic sense (Polish, analytic, coanalytic, or the like).

> Is there a *sensible* definable topology on $H(\omega_1)$?

About this, I found in the book [Classification and Orbit Equivalence Relations](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=p7zyBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=hereditarily+countable+sets+polish+space&source=bl&ots=dSg8vfnNXx&sig=KpHH8DBUja1dgp2wFajkRJl1ZWM&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidp9WD-v7JAhXDkZAKHTp7AwcQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=hereditarily%20countable%20sets%20polish%20space&f=false) by Hjorth that one can map $H(\omega_1)$ into the set of isomorphism classes of countable binary structures. Now, the countable binary structures form indeed a Polish space, so the odds are that this identification would give as something at least as complicated as $\boldsymbol{\Pi}_1^1(2^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}})$ (since one has to say that the binary relation is well founded).

Comment: We can indeed put a probability measure on the set of all countable structures in a natural way; it's just that the well-founded ones, or the ones satisfying ZFC (or any sufficiently interesting first-order theory) will have measure zero, so we don't gain the ability to ask about further measure-theoretic distinctions within these classes.

Comment: Same deal for category - the set of models of ZFC will be meager. Basically, any reasonable "largeness" notion for sets of reals comes equipped with a notion of "suitably generic element", and models of a sufficiently interesting theory are not suitably generic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for your comment; actually the second one is far more helpful. In spite of that, I thought of the following analogy: The Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}$ is both null and meager; but nevertheless it admits a natural probability measure (when seen as $2^\mathbb{N}$). Is there any reason why the subset of ctms doesn't admit one?